# Process management: To be killed or Not to be killed

Tags: android, process-management, application-lifecycle

An observation: While I was developing my app on android, I noticed following two lines in LogCat. These occurred because of too much memory requirements of my own app. I have read that Android can decide when to get rid of a process that are not needed or because of memory requirements.

Does it mean the alarm will not trigger at all (when some other app has made it to kill)? The alarm is a critical service and should not be killed.

```
09-07 16:18:32.936: INFO/ActivityManager(63): Process com.android.alarmclock (pid 164) has died.
09-07 16:19:01.655: INFO/ActivityManager(63): Process com.android.mms (pid 204) has died.
```

(Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com.android.alarmclock` is not `AlarmManager`. It is the Alarm Clock application.

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare. Found that AlarmManager is a service